# Position of element is outside container

Tags: css

I experience something odd here.

1. Why is `.inp-inline` outside it's container `.inp-label-inline`?
2. Why does the height of the container `.inp-label-inline` change when pressing the checkbox?

https://jsfiddle.net/cyfbvdq7/

```
    <div class="inp-label-inline">
      <label>Label</label>
      <div class="inp-inline">
        <div class="inp-checkbox">
          <input id="cb" type="checkbox">
          <div id="cb_inner" class="inp-checkbox-inner" style="height:0;width:0"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

input{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    padding:.2em .5em;
    line-height:1.4;
}

input[type='checkbox']{
    position:absolute;
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;
    margin:-1px;
    opacity:0 !important;
}

label{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    padding:2px;
}

.inp-label-inline{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:2px;
    white-space:nowrap;
  background:red;
}

.inp-inline{
    display:inline-block;
}

.inp-checkbox{
    position:relative;
    display:flex;
    height:18px;
    width:18px;
  background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #a6a6a6;
}

.inp-checkbox-inner {
    background:#424242;
    margin:auto;
    border-radius:1px;
}

let toggle = false;
$('#cb').click(function(){
    toggle = !toggle;
  $('#cb_inner').css({
    height: toggle ? '10px' : '',
    width: toggle ? '10px' : ''
  });
});
```

Comment: Because you use white-space: nowwrap. property in .inp-label-inline class

Comment: And also remove the inline-block property from the label  if you want to both horizontal and add display:inline in label

Comment: If you could please elaborate what you are actually trying to achieve? I suspect the height changes because of the script..

Answer (score 0):

I do now know exactly why it behaves like this. But placing label inside the inline-block element seems to cause this problem.

Instead you can do it like this to make the label work as intended:

```html
<label class="inp-label-inline">
  Label
  <div class="inp-inline">
    <div class="inp-checkbox">
      <input id="cb" type="checkbox">
      <div id="cb_inner" class="inp-checkbox-inner" style="height:0;width:0"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: It seems only to solve one of the issues.. When you click the checkbox the second issue persists